# ReactJs: Setting video source url statically works, but setting it dynamically doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, cloudinary

I am trying to display a video using the `video` tag and a Url I receive from the backend.
The problem is that :
**Even though, everything works perfectly and I receive the right url, the video doesn't get displayed.**

When I set the **same url**, statically, it works!
I display the used src in the video tag  along with the videos here, they're exactly the same in both dynamic and static approach.
**Yet, the dynamic approach doesn't work**

[image]
Here's the code:

```
class ProfilePage2 extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Inside ProfilePage.componentDidMount");
    this.props.getCurrentProfile();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps: ", nextProps);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("Rerendering");
    // this.props.profile contains all the different profile data not just personal profile
    const { profile } = this.props.profile;
    console.log("deconstructed personal profile data: ", profile);
    let videoUrlToDisplay;
    if (profile) {
      videoUrlToDisplay = profile.videoURL;
    }
    if (videoUrlToDisplay == undefined) {
      console.log("videoUrlToDisplay is undefined.");
    } else {
      // This gets logged with the video url
      console.log(
        "videoUrlToDisplay is NOT undefined. This is its value: ",
        videoUrlToDisplay
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Setting source dynamically: </h1>
        <div>src= {videoUrlToDisplay}</div>
        <div>
          <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src={videoUrlToDisplay} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
          <hr />
          <br />
          <h1>Setting source statically: </h1>
          <div>src= {videoUrlToDisplay}</div>
          <div>
            <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
              <source
                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dmam8ayrw/video/upload/v1602733968/yvaor"
                type="video/mp4"
              />
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't see why this happens. Everything should work perfectly. The url I use in src gets logged and displayed correctly but the video doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this is a demo?  I copied your code into CodeSandbox with a video from the cloudinary docs and it [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-babbage-siid1?file=/src/App.tsx) both ways.  My inkling is that that string you are getting from the props isn't actually identical.  It might have some botched whitespace or something.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Hey Linda, I fixed the problem by copying code that used to work. Thanks for your help